# clang 3.9 on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, clang

I'm am using Ubuntu 19.04 trying to compile an older version of software (carla 0.7.0) that only allows getting compiled in clang-3.9

From my research online I have not found a way to install clang 3.9 on this version of Ubuntu and am wondering if there is a workaround that will let me install it in some way.

I managed to download clang 3.9 using the advice I got in the comments although the installation of carla 0.7 through tons of compilation errors in the boost section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, my guess is that Carla 0.7.0 will build with a modern Clang version and it's [this check](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/blob/7567184bd8956322b4e897b98336c9eb9bae2f60/Setup.sh#L18) that is probably saying it needs Clang 3.9:

```
# Require clang 3.9
command -v clang++-3.9 >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
  echo >&2 "clang 3.9 is required, but it's not installed.";
  echo >&2 "make sure you build Unreal Engine with clang 3.9 too.";
  exit 1;
}
```

If that's the case, you should probably just try symlinking `/usr/bin/clang++` to `/usr/bin/clang++3.9` and seeing if it compiles.

Assuming that doesn't work and it *really* wants that specific version of Clang or some kind of backwards incompatible changes were made between 3.9 and 6.0 of Clang, you can [prebuilt binaries](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#3.9.0) from Clang. You probably want the [3.9 for Ubuntu 16.04](https://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/clang+llvm-3.9.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04.tar.xz) since it's the "newest" one for this old version.

Once you have that you can extract all of that stuff to `/usr/local` as root. I did notice that it does not come with a `clang++3.9` binary, so I'm not sure where the Carla developers got that from. You'll need to symlink `/usr/local/bin/clang++` to `/usr/local/bin/clang++3.9` to fix that too.

There could be *more* dragons if they've done something weird with how they find includes directories as well. If you can use a newer version of Carla you should since they now use CMake and many other proper build techniques.

Comment: I tried changing every mention if clang 3.9 to clang 8 which I already had installed and it does give some wierd errors. I'll try downloading clang 6 and do that again.

Comment: I am not sure where to put the extracted folder in exactly, I found that my already installed clang 8 is inside /usr/lib/clang. you wrote that I should put it in /usr/local but I don't think thats the right spot, would love some clarification

Comment: `/usr/local` is the correct spot to put binaries and files installed outside of the package system. You shouldn't overwrite files in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib` since those are files managed by the package manager, and it will get mad or at the least overwrite your files later. Look at your `$PATH` and you'll see that `/usr/local/bin` comes earlier and binaries from there will be found first, hence overriding the ones in `/usr/bin`

Comment: So I put it in /usr/local. I feel like I should do something else. Right now /usr/local/bin is empty and running clang --version still prints 8.0 instead of the downloaded 3.9

Comment: You need to extract the entire contents of the tar.xz file into `/usr/local`. Since the tar.xz file contains `bin/` and `include/` directories you will end up with a `/usr/local/bin/clang++` file. Then when you run `clang++` you should see 3.9.

Comment: Okay it worked, when writing `clang --version` and `clang++ --version` I do get 3.9 now. Carla still says I don't have clang 3.9 available though.

Comment: As I mentioned this is because you need to symlink `/usr/local/bin/clang++` to `/usr/local/bin/clang++3.9` to match the check they have for that file.

Comment: One more step I had to do was symlink /usr/local/bin/clang++-3.9 to /usr/local/bin/clang++3.9 and now it does compile, although with tons and tons of errors :(